# Why Doesn't Judaism Have A Call To Prayer?

Tags: halacha, minhag, tefilla

Is there anything in the Torah or the Talmud forbidding Judaism from establishing a call to prayer (of the type Islam has)?

Comment: @LN6595 Ever Time I Have Ever Been To A Synagogue I Have Never Heard Once A Member Of The Synagogue Calling Congregants To Prayer

Comment: http://www.torah.org/learning/ravfrand/5767/kisisa.html?print=1# paragraph 9.

Comment: No need to establish one. The Gemara (can't think of where just now) says that Aharon HaKohen used to call people to worship with *Barekhu* and - before the "kabbalah" insituted a host of things that are supposedly meant to come first (e.g. *qorbanoth*, *pesuqei de-zimra*, etc.) - this was was the announcement and call to prayer in the synagogue. In fact, Islam likely got their concept from us since during the time of the *Bayith Sheni* there were callers who announced halakhic times throughout the day. Kol tuv.

Comment: what about "barchu" before shema? Also in the beis hamikdash there were trumpets in addition to the shofar

Answer (score 4):

There were various methods used to wake people for prayer and to announce the times.

For example, [Prayer – waking people up to pray](http://strangeside.com/prayer-waking-people-up-to-pray/) gives the following examples.

> What happened when there was  a need to wake up an entire tzibbur  on
>   a daily basis? During Medieval  times, this was the of the
>   shulklappers (a term first appears in a non-Jewish published in 1225)
>   whose was to klap (knock) on peoples’ shutters and doors to indicate
>   it was time to get up and shul. This was generally the shamash of the
>   shul. The profession  must have been common as surnames  like
>   Shulklapper and Klapper are still extant.
>
> The custom of rousing people up for  avodah and prayer extends all the
>   way  back to the Bais Hamikdosh. Among the  people appointed over
>   various duties in  the Bais Hamikdosh, the Mishnah (Shekalim  5:1)
>   counts Gevini the Announcer,  whom, the Yerushalmi (ibid) explains, 
>   used to cry out every morning, “Rise,  Kohanim, for the sacrificial
>   service,  Levi’im to sing, and Yisroel to stand by  [as
>   representatives of the nation].” ...
>
> It has been claimed that the custom of  waking people with a
>   shulklapper died  at the end of the 19th century and that its  only
>   remnant are antique shulklapper  hammers on display in museums.  This
>   is not strictly true. The shulklapper  persists in modern guise.
>   Instead of  old time shulklappers racing through the  marketplace
>   warning shops to close up,  Shabbos niggunim now waft from
>   loudspeakers  to apprise people when Shabbos  or Yom Tov are about to
>   begin. Although  funerals are no longer announced  by a klap at the
>   door, some communities  still announce them from car-mounted 
>   loudspeakers.
>
> And even Selichos have not been  forgotten. Every year, R. Eizik Fried
>   of Kiryas Belz makes the rounds of his  Yerushalayim kehillah in his
>   car. As a  concession to modernity and perhaps due  to the height of
>   the apartment buildings,  he has replaced the shulklapper’s hammer 
>   with a speaker on his car from which  the ancient words still
>   resonate: Yisroel  am kodosh, kumu la.avodas haborei.

Answer (score 1):

There is the recognition that different prayer times (within a range) may work for different people. The Talmud praises those who start the morning prayers super-early so they reach the middle part right at sunrise, however it's also acknowledged that's not something we can expect everyone to do. As long as you get those prayers in sometime in the three hours after sunrise, that's still acceptable. So there's no one time at which you would be shouting out to the town, "wake up for prayers!"

Similarly, the afternoon prayers could be anywhere from ~1pm until sunset. So you could sound an alarm "we've now reached the earliest time for afternoon prayers!", or "it's 15 minutes until the last possible time for prayers, hurry up if you haven't yet done so!", but there's no one set time.

(In something structured like a school dormitory however, everyone is expected to be at the structured prayer service, and there will be a wake-up call accordingly.)

There are towns in Israel that have sirens or the like to announce the Sabbath is about to start, on Friday afternoon. And the Talmud speaks similarly of trumpets to warn people that Passover is beginning soon, they have to get rid of their bread. But those are clearly-demarcated deadlines, whereas prayer times are ranges.